# Ruta ELOQUENT /categorias existe y el error dice que no existe

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Al intentar insertar un dato en la base de datos. Nombre de categoria en este caso, devuelve error diciendo que URL /categoria no existe. Parece que en los route:list sí aparece. ¿Qué hago mal?

El ROUTE:LIST muestra las siguientes rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error dice que la ruta /categorias no existe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Rutas en web.php:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador y modelo de "Categoria" creados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CategoriaController contiene:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo Categoria de momento vacío:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Base de datos (es la columna "nombre" la que se pretende insertar):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Siempre que trabajo con laravel prefiero utilizar laravelcollective/html para no tener esos problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque técnicamente resolviste tu inconveniente, expondré lo siguiente:

- Si ya estas trabajando con controladores de tipo *resource* entonces tienes rutas de este tipo:

Listado de rutas

```
Verb          Path                         Action  Route Name
GET           /categorias                  index   categorias.index
GET           /categorias/create           create  categorias.create
POST          /categorias                  store   categorias.store
GET           /categoria/{categoria}       show    categorias.show
GET           /categorias/{categoria}/edit edit    categorias.edit
PUT|PATCH     /categorias/{categoria}      update  categorias.update
DELETE        /categorias/{categoria}      destroy categorias.destroy
```

Dado lo anterior, entonces en tu form, donde esta el atributo `action` usar el helper **route()** del siguiente modo:

```
<form action="{{ route('categorias.store') }}">
```

Como observamos pasamos como argumento del método el nombre de la ruta que dentro de si misma indica a que método del controlador de tipo *resource* esta apuntando

Comment: Corregido. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Solucionado.
El error era en el action del formulario. Tenía puesto:

```
action="/categorias"
```

y hay que poner:

```
action="categorias"
```